RUN npm install doesn't finish
I'm following a tutorial to create a docker image on an Alpine instance that runs a self hosted website with NodeJS.
the RUN npm install doesn't seem to finish and I've let it run for more than an hour, and no helpful logs are created anywhere
dockerfile:
# Test web app that returns the name of the host/pod/container servicing req
FROM node:current-alpine

LABEL org.opencontainers.image.title="Hello Docker Learners!" \
      org.opencontainers.image.description="Web server showing host that responded" \
      org.opencontainers.image.authors="@nigelpoulton"

# Create directory in container image for app code
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Copy app code (.) to /usr/src/app in container image
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Set working directory context
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install dependencies from package.json
RUN npm install

# Command for container to execute
ENTRYPOINT [ "node", "app.js" ]



I would suggest to change the docker layer from node:current-alpine to something more specific like node:22.11.0-alpine3.20
Ref: https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/node/22.11.0-alpine3.20/images/sha256-6fdb5a2cf4f4727c3ec873177330a984caf5c0851ec4bd80ef55da7f634c7722?context=explore
